# WebClient DownloadStringCompleted only fires once

Tags: c#, silverlight

I got this code:

```
private void LoadXML()
{
    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
    myWebClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(myWebClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
    myWebClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(strXMLPath));

}

private void myWebClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do stuff                       
}
```

`myWebClient_DownloadStringCompleted` is only fired first time I call `LoadXML()`. There is no errors on the xml file im trying to get, so I should be expecting a result. What am I missing?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line with DownloadStringAsync and note the strXMLPath. Then try to navigate to that path using the browser. Make sure you check the e.Error in the myWebClient_DownloadStringCompleted.

Comment: How did you verify? With a breakpoint in the Completed event?

Comment: @Henk Holterman Yes, I sat a breakpoint in myWebClient_DownloadStringCompleted

Comment: @Erno I cant check the e.Error since the code never gets there. The path and content is valid, if I reload the same URL, it doesnt work the second time, but it always works first time.

Comment: Well, it looks like it ought to work. Can you reproduce it in a new minimal App?

Comment: Do as I said, set the breakpoint at the Download call so you can test the uri by hand. Perhaps use Fiddler.

Comment: `strXMLPath` is not passed to the function (which it ought to be).  Perhaps on subsequent calls the current value of `strXMLPath` isn't what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to narrow the problem down. I had the silverlight object inside an `asp:updatepanel`, when I moved the silverlight object outside the updatepanel, things started to work.